# Why is phpqrcode rerunning all of the PHP before QRCode::png() is called?

Tags: php, mysql, qr-code

My question involves the use of the PHP QR Code library found here: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/.

When I run the code below, the QRCode::png() call at the end re-runs all of the previous code on the page so that a second, new random string is generated and the insertion query is run a second time. So I end up with two new rows in the table instead of the desired one.

So the obvious question is: **How do I get my QR code without running the second insertion query?**

```
// Connect to the database *
require_once 'db_connect.php';

// Function to generate a randomized string *
function F_generateRandomString($length = 4) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

// do-while loop to make sure we have a randomized *
// string that isn't alrady in the database        *
do {
    $random_string = F_generateRandomString();
    $q_random_check = "SELECT random_string FROM test_table WHERE random_string = '$random_string'";
    $r_random_check = mysql_query($q_random_check) or die (mysql_error());
    $num_random_check = mysql_num_rows($r_random_check);
}
while ($num_random_check);

// Insert data into database *
$q = "INSERT INTO test_table (random_string) VALUES ('$random_string')";
$r_q = mysql_query($q) or die (mysql_error());

// Form the URL for the QR Code *
$url = "https://example.com?$rxc_random";

// Generate the QR Code *
require_once 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';
QRcode::png($url);
```

(It may be worth noting that I DO end up getting the QR Code with this.)

---

**UPDATE**:
I think I found more of a "workaround" than a solution by performing the insert, then successfully using `header("Location: http://example.com?$rxc_random");` to shuffle the generation of the QR Code off to a separate .php page.

Comment: How are you running this script? `QRcode::png` is not *re-running* the page.  You might be loading it twice, reloading it or something like that.

Comment: I'm viewing it as a .php page in a browser. I'm loading the page once, then checking the database table. If I comment out the last line "QRcode::png($url);", the insertion query only runs once.